Help in simulation for bivariate residual entropy
I am reading a research paper research paper. Let $X=(X_1,X_2)$ be a bivariate random vector with survival function $\bar{F}(x_1,x_2)$.
The the condition residual entropy for the condition distribution $[X_1|X_2>t_2]$ is defined as $$H_1(f,t_1,t_2)=\int_{t_1}^\infty\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}F(x_1,t_2)}{\bar{F}(t_1,t_2)}\log \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}F(x_1,t_2)}{\bar{F}(t_1,t_2)} dx_1 .$$
The kernel estimator of $\bar{F}=\bar{F}(t_1,t_2)$ and $G_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}F(x_1,t_2), (i=1,2)$ are given by
$$\widehat{\bar{F}}(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{nh_n^2}\sum_{j=1}^n\bar{K_1}\left(\frac{x_1-X_{1j}}{h_n}\right)\bar{K_2}\left(\frac{x_1-X_{1j}}{h_n}\right),$$
and
$$\widehat{G}=\frac{1}{nh_n^2}\sum_{j=1}^n k_i\left(\frac{x_i-X_{ij}}{h_n}\right)\bar{K_k}\left(\frac{x_k-X_{kj}}{h_n}\right),~~i,k=1,2;i\neq k.$$
where $$\bar{K_i}(z)=h_n\int_{z}^\infty k_i(v) dv.$$
I want to do non parametric estimation of and MSE in under Gaussian kernel. Chosen unit variance, correlation coefficient 0.2, mean vector (2,2), for sample size 75, and $t_1=0.1=t_2$.
You can find table in above paper I have given link for further samples size and different $t_1,t_2$ values. I want to find R, python or MATLAB code for this or help me to learn. I have go through the youtube and some websites where I have learn to find MSE and BIAS for kernel density estimator but how to apply the above $H_1(X_1,t_1,t_2)$ is creating problem? I have struggling for weeks . Please someone help me! Thanks beforehand!
